# How to replace environment-specific config, not cascade

Tags: configuration, laravel, laravel-4

I want to have a local development environment configuration for my database.php. I've created a new config director in my app and copied the database.php file into it. I'm using MongoDB and on production, I'm using a replica set with multiple servers, but locally, I'm just running a single server, so my connection info for production has more options:

Production:

```
    ...
'connections' => array(

    'mongodb' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => array('mongoDBA', 'mongoDBB'),
        'port'     => 27017,
        'username' => 'myUserName',
        'password' => 'myPassword',
        'database' => 'theDatabase',
        'options'  => array('replicaSet' => 'myReplicaSet')
    )
),
```

Local:

```
    ...
'connections' => array(

    'mongodb' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'port'     => 27017,
        'database' => 'theDatabase'
    )
),
```

The problem is, when my local environment config loads, it merges the "connections" array. I want a way to completely replace the "mongodb" connection, so it's either one or the other, not both.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create different set of configuration files:

```
app/config/local/database.php
app/config/production/database.php
```

And delete the file (or what you don't want of it):

```
app/config/database.php
```

And the you have to set your environment as

```
local
development
```

**EDIT**

This is how I do set my environment flawlessly, so I don't have to deal with hostnames and still don't get my local environment conflict with staging and production.

Create a `.environment` file in the root of your application and define your environment and add your sensitive information to it:

```
<?php

return array(

     'APPLICATION_ENV' => 'development', /// this is where you will set your environment

     'DB_HOST' => 'localhost',
     'DB_DATABASE_NAME' => 'laraveldatabase',
     'DB_DATABASE_USER' => 'laraveluser',
     'DB_DATABASE_PASSWORD' => '!Bassw0rT',

);
```

Add it to your `.gitignore` file, so you don't risk having your passwords sent to Github or any other of your servers.

Right before `$app->detectEnvironment`, in the file `bootstrap/start.php`, load your `.environment` file to PHP environment:

```
foreach(require __DIR__.'/../.environment' as $key => $value) 
{
    putenv(sprintf('%s=%s', $key, $value));
}
```

And then you just have to use it:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function () {

    return getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'); // your environment name is in that file!

});
```

And it will work everywhere, so you don't need to have separate dirs for development and production anymore:

```
<?php

return array(

    'connections' => array(

         'postgresql' => array(
              'driver'   => 'pgsql',
              'host'     => getenv('DB_HOST'),
              'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE_NAME'),
              'username' => getenv('DB_DATABASE_USER'),
              'password' => getenv('DB_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
              'charset'  => 'utf8',
              'prefix'   => '',
              'schema'   => 'public',
         ),

    ),

);
```

Note that I don't set a fallback:

```
return getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?: 'local';
```

Because, if I don't set the file, **I want it to fail** on every server I deploy my app to.

Comment: There's one caveat. The application is hosted in Amazon's cloud, which could add new instances (with new hostnames) as it auto-scales. If I have a production specific directory, rather than using production by default, wouldn't I have to specify each individual hostname I want to run production for?

Comment: Does it copies all production files to the new instances?

Comment: Yeah, it's pulled from our Git repo when the new instance starts, so it would be identical to any other servers we have running, but the hostname of the machine would be different, so the array in `detectEnvironment` would not contain the hostname for the new instance.

Comment: Then my edit should work for you. This is how I use environments in my application. Laravel has a similar way of setting that but, still, you have to guess the environment name via hostname or anything else, which takes you to the very same problem, so I think my way is better, because the environment name also comes from the dotfile.

Comment: I like this. For the time being, I found that if I define "empty" values for the keys I don't want to set on my local config, I can accomplish what I need, but I'll probably move to your way shortly. Wouldn't I still run into a similar issue though with the auto-scaling--since the dotfile doesn't exist in Git, when the new instance starts up, there would be no dotfile. I could modify the instance start script to create and inset the dotfile, but that seems hacky.